# React. the order of the render method of nested components and how does it work with Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on a project that displays courses on a page. to get courses, I use redux to store the fetched courses. Below is the main course page:

Course.js:

```
class Course extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: "",
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <CourseWrapper>
                {/* <Fragment> */}
                    <div className={"test"}>
                        {console.log(store.getState()),
                        this.props.currentCourse.length < 1 ? null : this.props.currentCourse[0]["units"]}
                    </div>
                        <Dashboard />
                    <div>
                        {}
                    </div>        
                {/* </Fragment> */}
            </CourseWrapper>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return{
        currentCourse: state.courses.currentCourse,
    }
}
```

I emit 'getCourse()' action inside the constructor of CourseWrapper component.

CourseWrapper.js:

```
class CourseWrapper extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);  
        console.log("wrapper")
        this.props.getCourseTest("noUse");
    }

    render(){    
        return(
            <div>
                {console.log(this.props.children),
                this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return {
        getCourseTest: noUse => dispatch(getCourse(noUse)),
    }
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(CourseWrapper);
```

When I checked the console.log, I found that **1.** the first log is the one under  that shows the initial state of the store having no courses, then **2.** "wrapper" inside CourseWrapper.js constructor, and next **3.** children wrapped by , and finally **4.** the 'store.getStore()' again under  containing the expected course object.

My Questions are: why is the first log the initial state of the store instead of "wrapper"? and it doesn't have course obj inside. it leads to the next question that originally I think the constructor of CourseWrapper is called first, which dispatch 'getCourse' action, then its children get rendered. However, the logs showed that somehow {console.log(store.getState()) gets called first, doesn't CourseWrapper being rendered first? or I have some misunderstanding of how render actually arrange nested components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

   > Calls to `setState` are **asynchronous** - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately ...
2. `CourseWrapper` used inside `Course` that means `CourseWrapper` constructed **inside** `Course.render`... and
3. `render` actually does not render anything it constructs a description of that what should be rendered by React some time later. You can say that JSX translates to something like

   ```
   render() {
     return(
       create_node(CourseWrapper,
         ...
         create_node(div,
           ...
           console.log(store.getState()),
           ...
         )
       )
     )
   }
   ```

   So, as you can see `console.log(store.getState())` called inside `Course.render`, and then somewhere in `create_node` called a `new CourseWrapper` and then `CourseWrapper.render`, and only then `console.log("wrapper")`

   *(Don't think of it as an actual React algorithm, it's just and overly simplyfied principle)*
4. Then following the same idea: `<div>`... OK, `<div>` is difficult to call a child of CourseWrapper... Let's say that `CourseWrapper.render` looks like this

   ```
   render(){    
       return(
           <div>
               <SomeChild/>
               {this.props.children}
           </div>
       )
   }
   ```

   then SomeChild is a child of `CourseWrapper`, and `this.props.children` - also its children, but while `this.props.children` have been already created inside `Course` **before** `CourseWrapper`, `SomeChild` was created inside `CourseWrapper` **after** it

Comment: That translation helps a lot! looks to me that it's compiled in a way that console.log(store.getState()) gets executed first, then create_node(div, finally wrapper. Correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, before rendering, component should get its children, you can even find them in props.children in parent's constructor. So properties for children JSX objects should be calculated first.

1. console.log(store.getState()) will be calculated as it is inside of div JSX
2. CourseWrapper constructor calls and get div as children
3. render function of CourseWrapper invokes
4. If CourseWrapper rendering any other components - their constructors and render functions invoke

Comment: I see. is there a workaround? My idea is that instead of using 'props.childern', I put all those actual contents inside CourseWrapper class so that it follows the order

Comment: @HanayoZz, it is okey, you dont need to use children if it is not necessary, i just tell you that before component will be initialized it should get properties, and everything that you wraped inside it is a property children. It can not be initialize before it will get property children

Comment: so to double check, generally, when invoking render(), the element gets rendered first is the children inside outer tags, not those outer tags themselves. Is that correct?

Comment: @HanayoZz, I was not accurate enough, i will fix my answer now

Comment: ya I found the Babel complier actually helps me understand how they were rendered.